How to tune hyperparameters for low calibration error under small dataset
I'm studying which variant of variational autoencoders (VAE) gives better expected calibration error (ECE) (see also this doc) under small dataset. According to google's tuning playbook, to compare the scientific hyperparameter, we need to "optimize away" nuisance hyperparameters. When applied to here, it means to compare the VAE variants in terms of ECE, we need to find the best set of other hyperparameters (e.g. learning rate) for each VAE variant in terms of ECE, such that the comparison between VAE variants is fair enough. Another rule of thumb, apparently, is that we should tune hyperparameters on validation set instead of the test set.
The problem is, to reliably compute ECE, we need a relatively large dataset, which means the validation set has to be large enough, but in my case the validation set will not be large enough, since it's part of a small training set. I'm using synthetic data, and therefore I can enlarge the validation set any time. So my question is, should I enlarge the validation set while optimizing over the nuisance hyperparameters like learning rate?
Thank you so much!

For small datasets, you may be better off taking a Bayesian approach and marginalising over (integrating out) the nusisance parameters rather than optimising them out.

Synthetic data can be highly problematic. If you feed in the kind of structure your model can detect and model, but you apply the model later to data that exhibits different structure, your model will be too confident. And if you just keep on feeding in your synthetic data, your model will be more and more confident that it understands this data... and therefore its confidence will be farther and farther away from reality.

@DikranMarsupial Could you please elaborate on it a bit? How is the Bayesian approach related to computing ECE on small dataset? Thank you so much!

@StephanKolassa Thanks for your comment! It's indeed true. I use synthetic data here primarily to make visualization etc. more convenient. The model won't be trained on synthetic data when dealing with real-world problems.

@Kaiwen essentially it means averaging the output of models with different hyper-parameter values, weighted by the posterior probability of the hyper-parameter values.  The problem with optimising the hyper-parameter values is that it is very easy to overfit the selection criterion if it is based on a small sample of data, see my paper (with Mrs Marsupial) https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf

Why you expect a small training data can fairly compare variants of VAE models which are supposed to be re-trained by a bigger real data set later on? In addition, same model may require different hyperparameters when scaled to larger datasets. Small datasets might not reveal the full complexity of tuning required for a fair comparison.

@cinch Thanks for your comment! Seems that my previous comment is somewhat misleading ... sorry about that. I'm not re-training on bigger real data. The problem I'm studying is only available as small dataset, so to begin with, I explore different variants of VAE with small synthetic data, and try to see which attains better calibration.
